# LICENSE.txt when loading data into tensorflow transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, filepath

I am using code provided by tensorflow to load data: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/text

When I put in my own photos, it sends to a different directory. The code wants attributions from my LICENSE.txt, but I am not sure what the purpose of this code segment is.

I made my own LICENSE.txt file by just making a text file with each line being a title of an image. When I do this, it makes attributions a dictionary in which each key is the filename and each corresponding value is ''. When I run another method, I get a key error for every file.

```
import os
attributions = (data_root/"LICENSE.txt").open(encoding='utf- 8').readlines()
attributions = [line.split('\n') for line in attributions]
print(attributions)
attributions = dict(attributions)

import IPython.display as display

def caption_image(image_path):
    image_rel = pathlib.Path(image_path).relative_to(data_root)
    return "Image (CC BY 2.0) " + ' -'.join(attributions[str(image_rel)].split(' - ')[:-1])

for n in range(3):
  image_path = random.choice(all_image_paths)
  display.display(display.Image(image_path))
  print(caption_image(image_path))
  print()
```

I do not really know what to expect when I run the for loop in jupyter notebook, but it gives me a key error, the key being the file name.

Comment: Hi shar! Welcome to SO! Try to be more explicit about the question, since that will help others to help you. It seems to me the question is "what is the purpose of LICENCE.txt" but I'm not sure if that is what you really are looking for. Please clarify your question further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote that tutorial. The license lookup is only there so we can directly arttribute the individual photographers when we publish it. If you're working with your own images you don't need that part of the code at all.

All it's really doing is choosing a random image and displaying it. You can simplify it to:

```
import os

import IPython.display as display

for n in range(3):
  image_path = random.choice(all_image_paths)
  display.display(display.Image(image_path))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help with License. We got the image loading file to work and are now trying to use the transfer learning file here: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/images/transfer_learning. Do you know how we can use the data from the data loader in the transfer learning file? The default is the cats and dogs dataset, and we do not know how to change it. We are novice programmers using this for a biology project.

Comment: The transfer_learning example has a `Dataset` object called `train_batches`. In `load_data/images`, after the "ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)" line the dataset should be equivalent to `train_batches`, and should be interchangeable.